# pattern match block of code in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Im learning Scala and I stumbled upon a problem with pattern matching:
I would like to pass a block of code to an akka.actor so the actor can execute it, its just for a tutorial so I don't have an explicit example of where i want to use it, anyways what I am trying to do looks something like this:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
    case (block: => Unit) => block
    case _ => println("cant work with that")
}
```

unfortunately this wont work. I hope you guys get the idea of what i am trying to do.

## EDIT_1

I found out, that if i just pattern match `Any`, it will work, but since I match on `Any` now, this is very imprecisely and also dangerous:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
    case block => block
    case _ => println("cant work with that")
}
```

You see passed codeblocks are now matched and executed, but block matches `Any`thing and so this is still not what i want

Comment: maybe you forget the `match` word?

Comment: I dont think so, if I try to pattern match anything else like normal case classes it works just fine and despite of that this is just like my akka.actor tutorial pattern matches in the receive method of the actors

Edit1:
Just in case you're interested ->
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass parameters by name only as method's args. It's invalid to use it like this:

```
case (block: => Unit) => block
```

You can only:

```
case (block: Unit) => block
```

But you can send a function `() => Unit` :

```
 override def receive: Receive = {
    case block: (() => Unit) => block()
    case _ => println("cant work with that")
}

actorRef ! (() => println("Hello"))
```

Comment: really, you shouldn't pass messages of type Unit to your actor. As you said, it is just for a tutorial!

Comment: oh okay?! I thought this would be a nice way to use actors -> generating some and give them codeblocks to execute, would this be a bad practice?

Comment: I think, you should read more about actor model and why it is used. In your case, a good practice is to send immutable messages (for example case class instances) to actor to ask him to run one of his internal methods.